# Why does AWS XRay require 'UseExceptionHandler' and 'UseStaticFiles' in AspNetCore?

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, aws-xray

I'm following [Amazon's documentation to enable XRay](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-sdk-dotnet-messagehandler.html#xray-sdk-dotnet-messagehandler-startupcs) in one of our Lambda APIs under Api Gateway, and I noticed it tells you to add 3 middlewares to the configuration:

- `UseExceptionHandler`
- `UseXRay`
- `UseStaticFiles`

The first and third middlewares are native AspNet integrations, while the second is the actual Amazon XRay implementation. The documentation never states why the other 2 are needed. Instead, it has this to say about ordering:

> Always call UseXRay after UseExceptionHandler to record exceptions. If you use other middleware, enable it after you call UseXRay.

It is not clear to me if the exception handler is even *necessary*, or if they just mean that, "if you happen to have it, add XRay after it".

The documentation says nothing about `UseStaticFiles`.

I want to know why Amazon is making me add these other middlewares before proceeding with the change. If they really need to be added, there must be a documented reason for doing so.

In particular, this is giving me a few problems with `UseExceptionHandler`, [which doesn't appear to be working correctly with an OData-enabled API](https://github.com/OData/AspNetCoreOData/issues/60) which is my current case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not necessary to use exception or static files handlers when using X-Ray middleware. But if you have an exception handler in your application already and you want to record the inner exception stack, make sure to call:

1. `UseXRay` after `UseExceptionHandler` in .NET Core 2.0.
2. `UseXRay` in the beginning of http pipeline in .NET Core 2.1 and above.

See: https://github.com/aws/aws-xray-sdk-dotnet/tree/master#aspnet-core-framework-net-core--nuget

Comment: Could you elaborate why the documentation asks one to add those handlers if they are not necessary?